# C# File Path Within Class Library

Tags: c#, xsd, directory

I have a console application (MasterApp) that calls a class Library (ProcessFile). One of the functions inside of ProcessFile, takes in an xml document and validates it against an xsd. The xsd is stored under a folder under ProcessFile project. I am currently reading the file using an absolute path.

I want to be able to deploy my MasterApp to a server, but the only way I can get it to work is if I also copy over the ProcessFile project folder, since I am using an absolute path. I don't want to use an absolute path, if I can.

Is there a way to keep the xsd under the ProcessFile library, but be able to use it when running MasterApp on the server? Is there some kind of build process I need to do?

I thought about just putting the xsd under a folder under MasterApp, but I am trying to keep MasterApp decoupled from ProcessFile as much as I can. ProcessFile should be able to validate against the xsd, without MasterApp knowing about the xsd.

Comment: Put the path of the XSD file in a config option then pass this path to your library that now knows how to find the file. Other option is to assume the file to be in the same folder where your program runs and open it without giving any path

Comment: how are you storing / accessing the file path.. is it hard coded..? or is it stored in a .config file..:? can you get at the path of where the exe is located..?

Comment: @MethodMan The file path is currently hard coded. Since I am only deploying the MasterApp to the server, the xsd doesn't get copied over since I don't deploy ProcessFile.

Comment: @Steve How can I get the xsd to be copied to a location that MasterApp has access to during build? If I use "Copy To Output Directory", that just outputs it to ProcessFile's bin folder.

Comment: don't hard code your path @dburgener, store the paths in a .config file.. so that later down the road if you need to change the path.. you change it in the .config file and don't have to recompile to code every time you change something

Comment: And that's correct. When you application runs it uses the library that is copied in that folder (and when you distribute your app you put the library in the same folder of the executable)

Comment: @MethodMan I don't want MasterApp to have to know about the xsd file, so I can't add it to the app.config.

Comment: @Steve Is there a build process that could copy the library over for me during the build process, or do I just need to do that during the deploy process?

Comment: When you references the library from your main project it will be copied to the folder where your project runs (Usually BIN/DEBUG while in VS session)

Comment: @Steve The dll for the library gets copied over, but the xsd file doesn't.

Comment: And here you need to set the Copy to Output directory too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed your schema into your ProcessFile/MasterApp assembly and extract it as and when you need to validate xml. If you are not sure about how to embed then read [this.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114997/Embedding-and-Using-Resources-from-Net-Assembly)

```
// Get the assembly that contains the embedded schema
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("namespace.Yourschema.xsd"))
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    XmlSchema schema = XMLSchema.Read(reader, new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler));
}
```